# Add a record in my panel route my domain from host.com to www.host.com in dot net panel

Tags: 301-redirect, asp.net, .net, no-www, control-panel

Is there a way to enter a new register to route all the request to myhost.com to www.myhost.com in the dot net panel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Dot Net Control Panel does not offer this feature and you will need add something like this to your current configuration.

```
if (!Request.Url.Authority.StartsWith("www"))

{

    string url = string.Format("{0}://www.{1}{2}",

            Request.Url.Scheme,

            Request.Url.Authority,

            Request.Url.PathAndQuery);

           Response.Redirect(url, true);
}
```